# Print Labels in a Label Printer using Java

Tags: java, printing

For the past 3 hours, 2 carbon inks and 2 rolls of Labels, I still can't print a single one. Been strugling for this for the whole day and still didn't figure anything out. It seems that everything is base on luck by the looks of it.

```
class MyPrintable implements Printable {
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pageIndex) {
        if (pageIndex == 0) {
            Paper paper = new Paper();

            paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, 320, 115);
            paper.setSize(340, 128);

            pf.setPaper(paper);

            try {
                BufferedImage read = ImageIO.read(new File("tmp/conv/foo.png"));
                g.drawImage(read.getScaledInstance(220, 50, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH), 40, 10, null);
            } catch (IOException ex) {

            }

            return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
        }
        return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }
}
```

I need to print a single barcode in ONE label. The label size is 9 cm wide and 3,4 cm tall. Which brings me to 340 pixels wide and 128 pixels tall. That's why I set the image size to those values.

The problem is, when I tell the printer to print, it prints the barcode on the 8th label. It goes all the ways past the 7 first labels and print the things in between the 7th and 8th label ALL THE TIME. I have no idea why and I already tried with every possivel value. I set the size to 0px, the imageable size do 0px, the image scaled size to 0px and still it goes all the way to the 7th-8th label.

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't change the Paper in the print method, it will,have no effect, Java has already setup the paper before this method is called. Take a look at [thid question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803741/printing-in-java-to-label-printer/11805237#11805237) for an example

Comment: Thank you MadProgrammer! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!
that helped a lot!

Comment: Its always nice to know something did helped. If you found the answer of use, an up vote is always appreciated ;)