# Printing a label from Brother QL-570

Tags: java

Im not sure if this is possible but before I purchase this I want to make sure I will be able to print a label from it with custom text. 
i.e. have this on the label

```
L.LB  
13/11/15
```

Ive had a good look through questions about this printer but most answer comments say it doesnt work.

Would Just have a JTextBox and calling print() and having this as the default printer be acceptable?

Comment: If it has a standard printer driver, then yes.  I've used a [Dymo LabelWriter 400 and the Java Printer API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803741/printing-in-java-to-label-printer/11805237#11805237) before

Comment: @MadProgrammer no where in that resource can I see a method of just implementing a string which is all I want. Isnt there an easier way to do it

Comment: Nope.  Printing pretty much drops straight down the low level Graphics layer