# Guide to Printing in Label Prints

Tags: java, c#, printing, zebra-printers

I am developing a POS application that need to print labels including a barcode.

We have a Zebra GT800 printer.

I have tired JSF application and Java 2D Print, but both not successful.

What is the best way to print labels? I can use c# if needed.

Can we use the same printing we do in normal printers or do we have to design a label and sent a command.

I googled, but failed to find a good resource.

Can anyone guide me to print labels.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing in Java to Label Printer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11803741/5221149)

Comment: I tried that code, but the labels spreads over several labels and prints landscape. Changing values can not prevent that. Multiple pages are printed for one print.

Comment: try use RawPrint and send a ZPLll code, an example of zpl code is : ^XA ^FO50,50^A0N,30,32^FD Hello World!!^FS ^XZ

Comment: What is rawprint ?

Comment: Is there any reference to study how to send RawPrint commands?