# Printing to a Dymo labelprinter from Java

Tags: java, printing, dymo

I'm trying to print a label on my Dymo LabelWriter 450, but am having a hard time.

The issue I am dealing with now is that I can't even seem to fill the entire label, there seems to be a left margin of about 0.6mm that I don't get when I print using the Dymo software.

Ideally I would use an SDK, but I am unable to find a Dymo Java SDK.

This is the result I'm looking for
[image: Result I'm looking for]

This is what I've got so far
[image: current label]

I modified some code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11805237/2525319) to get to this result.

```
public class PrinterTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    if (printerJob.printDialog()) {
      PageFormat pageFormat = printerJob.defaultPage();
      Paper paper = pageFormat.getPaper();

      double width = fromCMToPPI(1.9);
      double height = fromCMToPPI(4.5);

      double horizontalMargin = fromCMToPPI(0.25);
      double verticalMargin = fromCMToPPI(0.1);

      paper.setSize(width, height);

      paper.setImageableArea(
          horizontalMargin,
          verticalMargin,
          width,
          height);

      pageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
      pageFormat.setPaper(paper);

      printerJob.setPrintable(new MyPrintable(), pageFormat);
      try {
        printerJob.print();
      } catch (PrinterException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  private static double fromCMToPPI(double cm) {
    return toPPI(cm * 0.393700787);
  }

  private static double toPPI(double inch) {
    return inch * 72d;
  }

  public static class MyPrintable implements Printable {

    @Override
    public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat,
        int pageIndex) {
      System.out.println(pageIndex);
      int result = NO_SUCH_PAGE;
      if (pageIndex < 1) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;

        double width = pageFormat.getImageableWidth();
        double height = pageFormat.getImageableHeight();
        double x = pageFormat.getImageableX();
        double y = pageFormat.getImageableY();

        System.out.println("x = " + x);
        System.out.println("y = " + y);

        g2d.translate((int) pageFormat.getImageableX(), (int) pageFormat.getImageableY());
        g2d.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, width - x, height - y));
        FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
        g2d.drawString("AxB", Math.round(x), fm.getAscent());
        result = PAGE_EXISTS;
      }
      return result;
    }
  }
}
```

If there is an SDK available that I missed, I would love to know where to find it. Otherwise, how can I get rid of this left margin so that I can actually fit everything on the label?

Thanks!